# Nessus installation problem on ubuntu 18

Tags: nessus

after running "sudo ./nessusd start" i get the following error inside the double quotation. how do i resolve this?
"Starting Nessus : ./nessusd: line 31: /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-service: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the article found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/starting-service-on-linux-throws-a-no-such-file-or-directory-error-794203722.html):

> Carriage return characters have been inserted into your init script. Shell scripts may not be read correctly when unexpected carriage returns are encountered. Typically this might occur when the file was created via a Windows system, text editor, or terminal, as Windows uses carriage return + line feed characters for line endings, whereas *nix systems only use line feed characters

**Resolution**

Remove the carriage return characters from the init script. This can be done with a sed one-liner:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r//g' /etc/init.d/your_init_script
```

This will remove the carriage return characters, after which you can start the service successfully

Comment: i've been running ubuntu on virtualbox. i ran this command with "sudo" added to it. still the same error.