# Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "then")

Tags: bash, proxy, syntax

I was sent a file to run to help setup my environment to work on my companies network but after making it executable I keep running into this error regarding a curly brace and it wanting then, I have tried adding then where it says that it wants it to no avail . Here is the code I am trying to execute It would be a godsend if somebody could correct it

```
echo "Setting up /etc/environment with proxy settings"

if ! grep -q proxy /etc/environment; 
    then
echo "Setting proxy system-wide"
{
    echo "http_proxy=\"http://proxy.cat.com:80/\""
    echo "https_proxy=\"http://proxy.cat.com:80/\""
    echo "ftp_proxy=\"http://proxy.cat.com:80/\""
    echo "socks_proxy=\"http://proxy.cat.com:80/\""
    echo "no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,cat.com,*.cat.com,165.26.78.0/23"
} >> /etc/environment
echo "Setting proxy for this session"
export http_proxy=http://proxy.cat.com:80/
export https_proxy=http://proxy.cat.com:80/
export ftp_proxy=http://proxy.cat.com:80/
export socks_proxy=http://proxy.cat.com:80/
else
if grep -q "https://proxy.cat.com" /etc/environment; then
    echo "/etc/environment contains invalid proxy settings, please remove all proxy settings from this file and rerun this script"
    echo "Execute the following command, remove all \"proxy\" lines, save and close: 'sudo gedit /etc/environment'"
    exit 2
fi
echo "/etc/environment already configured with a proxy"
fi
```

Comment: The file is corrupted. It makes no sense.

Comment: shellcheck doesn't find any issues with that code snippet. Are you sure you're showing us the whole code that fails?

Comment: @glennjackman thats the entire file. I try and execute it and it just says the first echo then the error message ....

Comment: @Pilot6 what makes you think it is corrupted ?

Comment: Show exactly how you execute it.

Comment: ... a carriage return after the `then` would produce this error (in `sh` - bash would be slightly different) - check for DOS style line endings

Comment: @glennjackman I mean the file is in downloads so I just navigate there and type sudo ./proxy.sh

Comment: @steeldriver should I remove all \ slashes ? The person who sent me the file advised to take out the extra \ but I was unsure what that meant since it is not my code

Comment: As steeldriver (implicitly) suggests, use `dos2unix` on that file. Then, because the file does not have a `#!` line, you should specify an interpreter: `sudo bash ./proxy.sh`

Comment: @glennjackman so the reason I need this proxy is I cannot use ubuntu servers or install /update software from command line. I just tried and am unable to install dos2unix but in running with bash I now get these new errors 


./proxy.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
'/proxy.sh: line 11: ` } >> /etc/environment

Comment: I can't find a reference for it, but executing a text file with no `#!` will use `/bin/sh` to interpret it (I recall)

Comment: Try this: `sed -i 's/\r$//' proxy.sh` to remove the carriage returns

Comment: @glennjackman wow! That worked, you are a lifesaver !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nessus installation problem on ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229943/nessus-installation-problem-on-ubuntu-18)